# How to iterate though the single object created by locator.all

Tags: python, automation, playwright, playwright-python

I am using Playwirght.
I have get all the elements possible through the page.locator.all()
and then itrated it thorught the for loop
but now i want to futher itrate throught the each element of the for loop.

```
 nav_bar_items = page.locator("li.nav-item").all()

    for nav_item in nav_bar_items:
        # title of the nav-bar
        title = nav_item.text_content()

        print(nav_item)
```

the nav_item reponse is

```
<Locator frame=<Frame name= url='https://demo/apps/subscriptions'> selector='li.nav-item >> nth=1'>  
<Locator frame=<Frame name= url='https://demo/apps/subscriptions'> selector='li.nav-item >> nth=2'>  
<Locator frame=<Frame name= url='https://demo/apps/subscriptions'> selector='li.nav-item >> nth=3'>  
<Locator frame=<Frame name= url='https://demo/apps/subscriptions'> selector='li.nav-item >> nth=4'>  
<Locator frame=<Frame name= url='https://demo/apps/subscriptions'> selector='li.nav-item >> nth=5'>
```

I have tried all the inbuilt that has been provided refer the docs as well.

i want to get the url from the nav_item response.

Comment: Those elements are iframes as far as I can see, so you should treat them as frameLocator probably. It is possible to know what is the page, is a public page? Without more details it is difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

With a normal list of elements you could be able to iterate over them and do whatever you want with them, but those elements are iFrames, so we need to use frame_locator. [Read more about frame_locator](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-framelocator)

I found a test page to reproduce the same behavior that your page has, here the example

```
import re
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context(record_video_dir="videos/")
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("https://ui.vision/demo/webtest/frames/")

    # We get our elements (All of them are iframes, as we said)
    elements = page.locator("//frame").all()

    # In this list we will save the frame_locators (Remember, your elements are iframes)
    frame_locator_list = []

    # For every element, we extract the unique selector
    for element in elements:
        element_str= str(element)
        selector_match = re.search(r"selector='([^']+)'", element_str) 
        # We save the frame_locator in our list
        frame_locator_list.append(page.frame_locator(selector_match.group(1)))

    # Now yes, now we can interact with our frame_locator.
    # In this example I am printing the title of every frame_locator
    for frame_locator in frame_locator_list:
        print(frame_locator.locator("//form/div").inner_text())
```

I hope it helps, but read carefully about frame_locators, it is the only way of interacting with iframes.